# React validate password and confirm password fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-state

I am trying to validate the values of `password` and `confirmPassword` fields as below. 
The issue is state update seems to be lagging by one event (character).
eg.: if password.value = "pass1234", confirmPassword.value at the time of validation is "pass123" though the "4" has been typed. So the validation is occurring before state is updated.
What is the best way to tackle this?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import Aux from "../../hoc/Aux/Aux";
import Button from "../../components/UI/Button/Button";
import Input from "../../components/UI/Input/Input";
import Spinner from "../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner";
import classes from "./Auth.module.css";
import * as actions from "../../store/actions/index";

class Auth extends Component {
  state = {
    controls: {
      name: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "name"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 4
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      email: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Email ID"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          isEmail: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      password: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "password"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 8
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      confirmPassword: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "confirm password"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 8,
          passwordMatch: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      }
    },

    isSignup: false
  };

  checkValidity(value, rules) {
    let isValid = true;
    if (!rules) {
      return true;
    }

    if (rules.required) {
      isValid = value.trim() !== "" && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.minLength) {
      isValid = value.length >= rules.minLength && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.maxLength) {
      isValid = value.length <= rules.maxLength && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.isEmail) {
      const pattern = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
      isValid = pattern.test(value) && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.isNumeric) {
      const pattern = /^\d+$/;
      isValid = pattern.test(value) && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.passwordMatch) {
      const pwd = this.state.controls.password.value;
      console.log("pwd: " + pwd);
      console.log("pwdConfirm: " + this.state.controls.confirmPassword.value);
      isValid = this.state.controls.confirmPassword.value === pwd;
    }

    return isValid;
  }

  inputChangedHandler = (event, controlName) => {
    let updatedControls = {
      ...this.state.controls,
      [controlName]: {
        ...this.state.controls[controlName],
        value: event.target.value,
        valid: this.checkValidity(
          event.target.value,
          this.state.controls[controlName].validation
        ),
        touched: true
      }
    };
    this.setState({ controls: updatedControls });
  };

  submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.isSignup) {
      this.props.onAuth(
        this.state.controls.email.value,
        this.state.controls.password.value,
        this.state.isSignup
      );
    } else {
      this.props.onSignUp(
        this.state.controls.name.value,
        this.state.controls.email.value,
        this.state.controls.password.value,
        this.state.controls.confirmPassword.value
      );
    }
  };

  switchAuthModeHandler = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { isSignup: !prevState.isSignup };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const formElementsArray = [];
    if (!this.state.isSignup) {
      for (let key in this.state.controls) {
        if (key !== "name" && key !== "confirmPassword") {
          formElementsArray.push({
            id: key,
            config: this.state.controls[key]
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (let key in this.state.controls) {
        formElementsArray.push({
          id: key,
          config: this.state.controls[key]
        });
      }
    }

    let form = null;
    form = formElementsArray.map(formElement => (
      <Input
        key={formElement.id}
        elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
        elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
        value={formElement.config.value}
        invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
        shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
        touched={formElement.config.touched}
        changed={event => this.inputChangedHandler(event, formElement.id)}
      />
    ));
    let button;
    if (!this.state.isSignup) {
      button = <button btnType="Success">LOGIN</button>;
    } else {
      button = <button btnType="Success">REGISTER</button>;
    }
    let buttonRegister = null;
    if (!this.state.isSignup) {
      buttonRegister = (
        <button btnType="SignUp" onClick={this.switchAuthModeHandler}>
          SIGN UP FREE!
        </button>
      );
    } else {
      buttonRegister = (
        <button btnType="SignUp" onClick={this.switchAuthModeHandler}>
          Back to Login!
        </button>
      );
    }

    if (this.props.loading) {
      form = <Spinner />;
    }

    let errorMessage = null;

    if (this.props.error && !this.state.isSignup) {
      errorMessage = <p>Email or Password is incorrect</p>;
    }

    if (this.props.error && this.state.isSignup) {
      errorMessage = <p>Please confirm email is valid and passwords match</p>;
    }

    if (this.props.error && this.state.isSignup) {
      let errorObj = JSON.parse(`${this.props.error}`);

      if (errorObj.code == "11000") {
        errorMessage = (
          <p>
            Email is already in use. Please reset your password, if you don't
            remember it
          </p>
        );
      }
    }

    let authRedirect = null;
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      authRedirect = <Redirect to={this.props.authRedirectPath} />;
    }

    return (
      <div className={classes.Auth}>
        {authRedirect}
        {errorMessage}
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          {form}
          {button}
        </form>
        {buttonRegister}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loading: state.auth.loading,
    error: state.auth.error,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null,
    role: state.auth.role,
    userName: state.auth.name,
    userPoints: state.auth.userPoints,
    userJourneyPoints: state.auth.userJourneyPoints,
    journeysCompleted: state.auth.journeysCompleted,
    userLevel: state.auth.userLevel,
    useHints: state.auth.useHints
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onAuth: (email, password, isSignup) =>
      dispatch(actions.auth(email, password, isSignup)),
    onSignUp: (name, email, password, confirmPassword) =>
      dispatch(actions.signUp(name, email, password, confirmPassword))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Auth);
```

Comment: can you share your code in sandbox?

Comment: not sure how to make this work in sandbox. But I have now provided the full component

Answer (score 0):

After taking a glance through your code, it seems like you could solve the issue by comparing `target.event.value` to the current state of `password` when `inputChangedHandler` is invoked due to changing the "confirm password" input. What you're currently doing is comparing the `confirmPassword` and `password` states before `confirmPassword` has the chance to update. The `target.event.value` of the "confirm password" input, however, would have the updated value at the time that `inputChangedHandler` is called.

An alternative solution could be to validate your form inside of `componentDidUpdate`, instead of validating as soon as `inputChangedHandler` is called. By validating inside `componentDidUpdate`, you ensure that the state has had time to update.